# Is Quota on Google APIs per Account or per Project?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

In console.developers.google.com, projects show quota and usage of their associated keys.  Unused projects under the same account (for the same api) show no quota usage. Yet, when a request is made from a project with "no usage" the quota jumps up to full and the request is denied.

This leads me to believe that quota is per *account* and not per project, is that true?

Specifics, on youtube data api my console quota is:

- Queries per day   50,000,000
- Queries per 100 seconds per user  300,000
- Queries per 100 seconds   3,000,000

So now I see that even if I made 20 projects, I would still be rate limited by user quotas.  But that should only matter if I'm using a client token on behalf of a user and I think I've seen this behavior when using an API server key.

Comment: We have noticed this as well. The only thing that can really explain this is this wording from google:

"If the quota of requesting a Google Analytics API is exceeded, the API returns an error code 403 or 429 and a message that the account has exceeded the quota." Not a generic message, but presumably this is how it works for every API.

Answer (score 0):

Based from Google documentations (which basically applies to all Google APIs), daily usage is tracked per project.

Sources:

- [Limits and Quotas on API Requests](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas)
- [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota)
- [Quota Usage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota)
- [Google Analytics - FAQ](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/provisioning/v3/api-quota-faqs)
- [Google Maps API - FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_pricing)